# fatal error C1083 while installing Odoo prerequisites

Tags: python-2.7, ldap, pip, odoo

I am facing an error while installing Odoo 11.0 community edition. The prerequisite process is ending up with fatal error C1083. I already tried these things.

1. Installed pip separately
2. Installed OpenLDAP through https://www.userbooster.de/en/download/openldap-for-windows.aspx
3. Installed Pyldap a fork of python-ldap https://www.lfd.uci.edu/~gohlke/pythonlibs/#pyldap

Nothing worked. I have Python27 64 bit on my windows10 machine.

This is the error which I am getting while running `pip install -r C:\unifiedexpert\odoo-11.0\requirements.txt`

The error trace which I am getting is:

```
    file Lib\ldap.py (for module ldap) not found
  file Lib\ldap\controls.py (for module ldap.controls) not found
  file Lib\ldap\extop.py (for module ldap.extop) not found
  file Lib\ldap\schema.py (for module ldap.schema) not found
  reading manifest file 'Lib\pyldap.egg-info\SOURCES.txt'
  reading manifest template 'MANIFEST.in'
  warning: no files found matching 'Makefile'
  warning: no files found matching 'Modules\LICENSE'
  writing manifest file 'Lib\pyldap.egg-info\SOURCES.txt'
  running build_ext
  building '_ldap' extension
  creating build\temp.win-amd64-2.7
  creating build\temp.win-amd64-2.7\Release
  creating build\temp.win-amd64-2.7\Release\Modules
  C:\Users\Nayyer\AppData\Local\Programs\Common\Microsoft\Visual C++ for Python\9.0\VC\Bin\amd64\cl.exe /c /nologo /Ox /MD /W3 /GS- /DNDEBUG -DHAVE_SASL -DHAVE_TLS -DHAVE_LIBLDAP_R -DHAVE_LIBLDAP_R -DLDAPMODULE_VERSION=2.4.28 -IModules -I/usr/include -I/usr/include/sasl -I/usr/local/include -I/usr/local/include/sasl -IC:\Python27\include -IC:\Python27\PC /TcModules/LDAPObject.c /Fobuild\temp.win-amd64-2.7\Release\Modules/LDAPObject.obj
  LDAPObject.c
  c:\users\nayyer\appdata\local\temp\pip-build-5aaqii\pyldap\modules\errors.h(8) : fatal error C1083: Cannot open include file: 'lber.h': No such file or directory
  error: command 'C:\\Users\\Nayyer\\AppData\\Local\\Programs\\Common\\Microsoft\\Visual C++ for Python\\9.0\\VC\\Bin\\amd64\\cl.exe' failed with exit status 2

  ----------------------------------------
  Failed building wheel for pyldap
  Running setup.py clean for pyldap
Failed to build pyldap
Installing collected packages: pyldap, PyPDF2, pyserial, six, python-dateutil, pytz, pyusb, PyYAML, qrcode, reportlab, requests, suds-jurko, python-stdnum, vatnumber, vobject, Werkzeug, XlsxWriter, xlrd, pypiwin32, xlwt, funcsigs, pbr, beautifulsoup4
  Found existing installation: pyldap 2.4.37
    Uninstalling pyldap-2.4.37:
      Successfully uninstalled pyldap-2.4.37
  Running setup.py install for pyldap ... error
    Complete output from command C:\Python27\python.exe -u -c "import setuptools, tokenize;__file__='c:\\users\\nayyer\\appdata\\local\\temp\\pip-build-5aaqii\\pyldap\\setup.py';f=getattr(tokenize, 'open', open)(__file__);code=f.read().replace('\r\n', '\n');f.close();exec(compile(code, __file__, 'exec'))" install --record c:\users\nayyer\appdata\local\temp\pip-qyihid-record\install-record.txt --single-version-externally-managed --compile:
    defines: HAVE_SASL HAVE_TLS HAVE_LIBLDAP_R
    extra_compile_args:
    extra_objects:
    include_dirs: /usr/include /usr/include/sasl /usr/local/include /usr/local/include/sasl
    library_dirs: /usr/lib /usr/lib64 /usr/local/lib /usr/local/lib64
    libs: ldap_r
    running install
    running build
    running build_py
    file Lib\ldap.py (for module ldap) not found
    file Lib\ldap\controls.py (for module ldap.controls) not found
    file Lib\ldap\extop.py (for module ldap.extop) not found
    file Lib\ldap\schema.py (for module ldap.schema) not found
    creating build\lib.win-amd64-2.7
    copying Lib\ldapurl.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-2.7
    copying Lib\ldif.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-2.7
    copying Lib\dsml.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-2.7
    creating build\lib.win-amd64-2.7\ldap
    copying Lib\ldap\__init__.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-2.7\ldap
    copying Lib\ldap\async.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-2.7\ldap
    copying Lib\ldap\compat.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-2.7\ldap
    creating build\lib.win-amd64-2.7\ldap\controls
    copying Lib\ldap\controls\__init__.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-2.7\ldap\controls
    copying Lib\ldap\controls\deref.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-2.7\ldap\controls
    copying Lib\ldap\controls\libldap.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-2.7\ldap\controls
    copying Lib\ldap\controls\openldap.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-2.7\ldap\controls
    copying Lib\ldap\controls\ppolicy.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-2.7\ldap\controls
    copying Lib\ldap\controls\psearch.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-2.7\ldap\controls
    copying Lib\ldap\controls\pwdpolicy.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-2.7\ldap\controls
    copying Lib\ldap\controls\readentry.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-2.7\ldap\controls
    copying Lib\ldap\controls\sessiontrack.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-2.7\ldap\controls
    copying Lib\ldap\controls\simple.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-2.7\ldap\controls
    copying Lib\ldap\controls\sss.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-2.7\ldap\controls
    copying Lib\ldap\cidict.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-2.7\ldap
    copying Lib\ldap\dn.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-2.7\ldap
    creating build\lib.win-amd64-2.7\ldap\extop
    copying Lib\ldap\extop\__init__.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-2.7\ldap\extop
    copying Lib\ldap\extop\dds.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-2.7\ldap\extop
    copying Lib\ldap\filter.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-2.7\ldap
    copying Lib\ldap\functions.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-2.7\ldap
    copying Lib\ldap\ldapobject.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-2.7\ldap
    copying Lib\ldap\logger.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-2.7\ldap
    copying Lib\ldap\modlist.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-2.7\ldap
    copying Lib\ldap\resiter.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-2.7\ldap
    copying Lib\ldap\sasl.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-2.7\ldap
    creating build\lib.win-amd64-2.7\ldap\schema
    copying Lib\ldap\schema\__init__.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-2.7\ldap\schema
    copying Lib\ldap\schema\models.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-2.7\ldap\schema
    copying Lib\ldap\schema\subentry.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-2.7\ldap\schema
    copying Lib\ldap\schema\tokenizer.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-2.7\ldap\schema
    copying Lib\ldap\syncrepl.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-2.7\ldap
    file Lib\ldap.py (for module ldap) not found
    file Lib\ldap\controls.py (for module ldap.controls) not found
    file Lib\ldap\extop.py (for module ldap.extop) not found
    file Lib\ldap\schema.py (for module ldap.schema) not found
    running egg_info
    writing requirements to Lib\pyldap.egg-info\requires.txt
    writing Lib\pyldap.egg-info\PKG-INFO
    writing top-level names to Lib\pyldap.egg-info\top_level.txt
    writing dependency_links to Lib\pyldap.egg-info\dependency_links.txt
    warning: manifest_maker: standard file '-c' not found

    file Lib\ldap.py (for module ldap) not found
    file Lib\ldap\controls.py (for module ldap.controls) not found
    file Lib\ldap\extop.py (for module ldap.extop) not found
    file Lib\ldap\schema.py (for module ldap.schema) not found
    reading manifest file 'Lib\pyldap.egg-info\SOURCES.txt'
    reading manifest template 'MANIFEST.in'
    warning: no files found matching 'Makefile'
    warning: no files found matching 'Modules\LICENSE'
    writing manifest file 'Lib\pyldap.egg-info\SOURCES.txt'
    running build_ext
    building '_ldap' extension
    creating build\temp.win-amd64-2.7
    creating build\temp.win-amd64-2.7\Release
    creating build\temp.win-amd64-2.7\Release\Modules
    C:\Users\Nayyer\AppData\Local\Programs\Common\Microsoft\Visual C++ for Python\9.0\VC\Bin\amd64\cl.exe /c /nologo /Ox /MD /W3 /GS- /DNDEBUG -DHAVE_SASL -DHAVE_TLS -DHAVE_LIBLDAP_R -DHAVE_LIBLDAP_R -DLDAPMODULE_VERSION=2.4.28 -IModules -I/usr/include -I/usr/include/sasl -I/usr/local/include -I/usr/local/include/sasl -IC:\Python27\include -IC:\Python27\PC /TcModules/LDAPObject.c /Fobuild\temp.win-amd64-2.7\Release\Modules/LDAPObject.obj
    LDAPObject.c
    c:\users\nayyer\appdata\local\temp\pip-build-5aaqii\pyldap\modules\errors.h(8) : fatal error C1083: Cannot open include file: 'lber.h': No such file or directory
    error: command 'C:\\Users\\Nayyer\\AppData\\Local\\Programs\\Common\\Microsoft\\Visual C++ for Python\\9.0\\VC\\Bin\\amd64\\cl.exe' failed with exit status 2

    ----------------------------------------
  Rolling back uninstall of pyldap
Command "C:\Python27\python.exe -u -c "import setuptools, tokenize;__file__='c:\\users\\nayyer\\appdata\\local\\temp\\pip-build-5aaqii\\pyldap\\setup.py';f=getattr(tokenize, 'open', open)(__file__);code=f.read().replace('\r\n', '\n');f.close();exec(compile(code, __file__, 'exec'))" install --record c:\users\nayyer\appdata\local\temp\pip-qyihid-record\install-record.txt --single-version-externally-managed --compile" failed with error code 1 in c:\users\nayyer\appdata\local\temp\pip-build-5aaqii\pyldap\
```

Comment: "Cannot open include file: 'lber.h': No such file or directory": you need to install include (header) files.

Comment: This might be due to odoo11 is by default running on python3.5 So you need to install pip3 and py3.5 in your system and re-run again via py3.5 interpreter.

Answer (score 0):

`$ sudo apt-get install libsasl2-dev  libldap2-dev libssl-dev`